# Rewrite Javascript for use in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm not very familiar with javascript and am unsure how to rewrite this code to work with Wordpress.  It gets a series of errors when the code executes.  One of the errors is similar to when I had to rewrite `$(document).ready(function(){` to `jQuery(function ($) {`.

```
// JavaScript Document
var chans = [];
var temparr = [];
var cSize = 0;
var lSize = 0;
var X = 0;
var Y = -1;


function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}


function myFunction(){
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
}

function subarray(responsData) {
    chans.push(responsData);
}

function cplcheck(){
    if (X == cSize) {
        process();
    }
}

function process(){
    if (X === cSize){
        setTimeout(myFunction, 500);

        X = -1;
        chans.sort(sortFunction);
        $("#logos").append("<table border='0'><tr>");
        while ( Y < lSize ) {
            Y = Y + 1;
            X = X + 1;
            if(Y == 3){
                $("#logos").append("</tr><tr>");
                Y = 0;
            }
            $("#logos").append("<td class='twitch' width='350' valign='top'>" + chans[X][0] + "<table border='0'><tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><a href='https://twitch.tv/" + chans[X][0] + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + chans[X][1] + "'></a></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>Playing: " + chans[X][2] + "</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>Status: " + chans[X][3] + "</tr><tr><td>" + chans[X][4] + " Viewers</td><td align='right'>" + chans[X][5] + " Followers</td></tr></table></td>");
        }
        if(Y == 1) {
            $("#logos").append("<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>");
        }else if(Y == 2){
            $("#logos").append("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
        }
            $("#logos").append("</tr></table>");    
        }

    }

jQuery(function ($) {
    $("body").addClass("loading");
    cSize = channels.length;
    channels.forEach(function (channel) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + channel,
            headers: {
                'Client-ID': "client"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                X = X + 1;
                if(data.stream != null){
                    lSize = lSize + 1;
                    temparr = [ channel,data.stream.preview.medium,data.stream.channel.game,data.stream.channel.status,data.stream.viewers,data.stream.channel.followers ];
                    subarray(temparr);
                    cplcheck();
                } else {
                    cplcheck();
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Here are the errors that are being generated.

[image: javascript errors]

Comment: A quick google search shows that Wordpress takes JQuery, so maybe the issue is there. Maybe the code is in JavaScript, and Wordpress is looking for JQuery syntax. That would explain why you had to change `$(document).ready(function(){` to `jQuery(function ($) {`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are try to do this for a single page then you should copy the whole code and put it in a php echo statement along with script tag. Now php wont work in wordpress page so you need to install a plugin like insert_php to your wordpress website.e.g.`[insert_php]echo '<script type="text/javascript">Your JS code here</script>';[/insert_php]`.
Else if you want to include it throughout the website then: check [Wordpress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Comment: Using `wp_enqueue_script( 'whoslive', '/scripts/whoslive.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);` didn't solve the problem.  It is still persisting.

Comment: Then did you try echo statement